# vaadin table vertically till but not beyond the bottom of the page, scrollbars as needed

Tags: layout, scrollbar, vaadin, vaadin7

In my vaadin 7 application I have a CSSLayout that contains a Tabsheet. The Tabsheet contains a horizontalLayout. The HorizontalLayout contains a Table.

The table have a varying number of columns (between 3 and 20, changes upon request).
I want this table to occupy all available space both horizontally and vertically.

Vertically however the table should not extend beyond the the screen. So in case of having more rows than it can display the table should have a vertical scrollbar. (That is the case if I set  the number of rows in table.setPageLength(), however I want to achieve this without setting explicit rownumbers, because I want the table to occupy all available space regardless of screensize, etc...)

Horizontally I also want a scrollbar if there are more columns then we have space for.

If I leave everything (csslayout, tabsheet, horizontallayout, table) default, I get the scrollbars, but I get a lot of space unused.

If I use setSizeFull() on  tabsheet, horizontallayout, table then I get no unused space, however I lose the horizontal scrollbar and I can't ever reach end of the table with the vertical scrollbar.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT -- UPDATE -- EDIT -- UPDATE --EDIT -- UPDATE --EDIT -- UPDATE**

Here is a sample code. On my screen it's impossible to scroll down to the last row of the table. (and equally impossible to use the horizontal scrollbar)

```
@Override
protected void init(@SuppressWarnings("unused") VaadinRequest request) {


     CssLayout css = new CssLayout();

        HorizontalLayout upper = new HorizontalLayout();
        OptionGroup first = new OptionGroup();
        first.addItem("AAA");
        first.addItem("BBB");
        first.addItem("CCC");
        first.addItem("DDD");
        first.addItem("EEE");
        first.addItem("Whatever");
        upper.addComponent(first);
        css.addComponent(upper);


        HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
        hl.setMargin(true);
        hl.setSpacing(true);
        IndexedContainer c = new IndexedContainer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            c.addContainerProperty("name" + i, String.class, "name" + i);

        Table table = new Table("Test table", c);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Integer id = (Integer) c.addItem();
            c.getItem(id).getItemProperty("name0").setValue(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        hl.addComponent(table);
        TabSheet tab = new TabSheet();
        tab.addTab(hl, "Table");
        css.addComponent(tab);

        hl.setSizeFull();
        table.setSizeFull();
        tab.setSizeFull();
        css.setSizeFull();

      setContent(css);

}
```

Comment: it would help to have a SSCCE.  also if you set the tabel.height, have you adjusted the pageLength?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't set the size full on the css layout or maybe there are some trouble with styles.

It's better posting some code in questions like *Why my code dosen't work?*. However I wrote a simple test following your description and work as expected.

**Edit**

Try with `VerticalLayout` instead `CssLayout`

```
public class TestTableApp extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        VerticalLayout css = new VerticalLayout();

        HorizontalLayout upper = new HorizontalLayout();
        OptionGroup first = new OptionGroup();
        first.addItem("AAA");
        first.addItem("BBB");
        first.addItem("CCC");
        first.addItem("DDD");
        first.addItem("EEE");
        first.addItem("Whatever");
        upper.addComponent(first);
        css.addComponent(upper);


        HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
        hl.setMargin(true);
        hl.setSpacing(true);
        IndexedContainer c = new IndexedContainer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            c.addContainerProperty("name" + i, String.class, "name" + i);

        Table table = new Table("Test table", c);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Integer id = (Integer) c.addItem();
            c.getItem(id).getItemProperty("name0").setValue(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        hl.addComponent(table);
        TabSheet tab = new TabSheet();
        tab.addTab(hl, "Table");
        css.addComponent(tab);

        hl.setSizeFull();
        tab.setSizeFull();
        table.setSizeFull();
        css.setSizeFull();
        // this do the trick
        css.setExpandRatio(upper, 0);
        css.setExpandRatio(tab, 1);

        setContent(css);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still investigating because it works by itself, but fails inside my application. (it occupies the whole screen leaving no space for other Panels above.)

Comment: Forget my previous comment. It works by itself, as a standalone example. But when I use it within my application it fails. In my application I have some Panels on the top.I suspect that the height of those panes make the table to 'overextend' to downward direction (beyond the edge of the screen). Therefore I can never reach the  bottom of the vertical scrollbar of the table, so there are rows in the table I can never see. To be precise the last row I can reach is row number 90 (out of 100).

Comment: @Regenbogenfisch OK, if you change the CssLayout for a VerticalLayout and set the expand ratios, it works. See edit